# Valgrind hooks in client code : Memory leak for particular functions

Tags: c++, c, valgrind

Are there are any Valgrind functions or macros available when used in the application code I can generate memory leaks wrt a particular function.
In other words I need to account for no memory leaks after calling a particular application function .

Comment: I’m not clear what you’re asking for.  If you are asking whether there is an API provided by Valgrind that allows you to set a marker before a function call and then check when the function returns whether any memory leaked, then I’m not sure but what did the manual say?   Generally, Valgrind scores because it works on programs that had no expectations of being run with Valgrind. It requires no API; it requires no linking with Valgrind libraries.

Comment: You may want to look into sanitizers provided by clang/gcc rather than using valgrind.

Comment: @Jonathan , yes you understood my question correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valgrind has two mechanisms for interaction between Valgrind and the app under test.

1. [gdbserver commands](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver) and here for [memcheck monitor commands](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.monitor-commands). You can start your app under Valgrind and then attach gdb. You can then issue commands to do things like generate a leak report at that instant. In your case you could use the `leak_check` command.
2. Valgrind [client requests](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.clientreq) and also [here](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.clientreqs). To use this you need to include Valgrind headers like "valgrind/memcheck.h" and recompile. Then there are a load of macros that you can use to do things like query the state of memory. In your case you could use `VALGRIND_DO_LEAK_CHECK`.

I wrote an article on using these mechanisms a few years ago, available online [here](https://accu.org/index.php/journals/1905).

Comment: Thanks that was useful info. Will go through that link.